# How can I make a DataGrid validation able to accept an empty cell in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have made a `DataGrid` that is bound to a `DataTable` which is filled by an `SqlDataAdapter`, and my `DataGrid` therefore type checks when a user edits in the `DataGrid`. This is fine, because it ensures that the correct type is committed to the database. However, when I try to edit the cell to being an empty cell, which I would think is `null`, the validation won't let me change the row, and I am therefore unable to commit the changes to the database. When I add a new row, though, I am able to add the row without any problems, as long as the columns that are empty are nullable in the database.

I am unable to define the columns in the `DataGrid`, because it is supposed to show different tables, and there is no way of knowing the structure of the tables before fetching them.

DataGrid:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid_Table" HeadersVisibility="Column" CanUserAddRows="true" RowEditEnding="dataGrid_Table_RowEditEnding"/>
```

Method for filling the DataTable and DataGrid

```
internal DataTable FillDataGridFromSelectedTable(User user, MainWindow mainWindow)
    {
        dt = new DataTable();

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
            {
                con.Open();

                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM " + Name, con))
                {
                    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                    sda.Fill(dt);
                    mainWindow.dataGrid_Table.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
                }
            }
   }
```

If there any way to work around this?

Thanks a bunch in advance.

Comment: it is impossible to answer your question unless you provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Thanks for answering. I will include the XAML for the DataGrid and the code behind for filling my DataTable. However, I do not see how this is of any help to any one :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference if someone needs the answer, I got it working using

```
private void dataGrid_Table_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
        {
            // Make all columns nullable
            ((DataGridBoundColumn)e.Column).Binding.TargetNullValue = "NULL";
        }
```

Now I have the issue that when I want to add a new row, the default values are shown when I enter the edit mode, and I would like these values to be empty strings. Due to the fact that some of the columns might be `int` type, I will try to work out another workaround this, and edit my post when it's done.

**EDIT:**

Fixed it by adding a InitializingNewItem event. Even though it didn't quite turn out the way I wanted to, this was the only way that worked, that I could find.

```
private void dataGrid_Table_InitializingNewItem(object sender, InitializingNewItemEventArgs e)
    {
        DataRowView drv = (DataRowView)e.NewItem;

        for (int i = 0; i < drv.Row.ItemArray.Count(); i++)
        {
            DataColumn col = drv.Row.Table.Columns[i];

            if (col.DataType.ToString() == "System.String")
            {
                drv.Row[i] = "";
            }
            else if (col.DataType.ToString() == "System.Int32")
            {
                drv.Row[i] = 0;
            }
        }
    }
```

`String` cells are empty, and `int` cells are 0, was works OK for the design.